# Invalid character when importing XML

Tags: import, data

I am having trouble importing XML data taken from Open Street Map.

This seems to be due to a problematic Asian character. Though the full file is quite large, here is an simplified example of the XML I am trying to import, with the problematic character(s) on line 3:

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmium/1.11.1">
<way id="148439614" version="3" timestamp="2019-01-15T12:47:33Z">
    <tag k="name" v="川ビル"/>
</way>
</osm>
```

Trying to import the above with `Import["foo.xml"]` gives the following error:

```
XML`Parser`XMLGet: Invalid character in attribute value (Unicode: 0xv) at Line: 3 Character: 23
```

There seems to be no problem with the file when checked with an external XML validator. Is this a problem with unsupported encodings? I am struggling to figure out what next steps to take, given my limited CS knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the problem is definitely with that first ideogram character in the v attribute. If I delete that character, the import works without error. If I apply FullForm to the string, it does look like Mathematica "sees" that character differently: `"v=\" \|020bb7\:5ddd\:30d3\:30eb \""`. The \: indicates unicode, but I don't recognize the \| format. Here's a very hackish workaround that might get you where you need to go...

Comment: `text = Import[pathToFile, 
  "Text"]`

`exportedString = 
 ExportString[text, "String", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]`

`xml = ImportString[exportedString, "XML"]`

Comment: sorry, I give up trying to format it nicely in a comment.

Comment: Anyway, what you end up with will be somewhat corrupted, but it'll have the XML structure. I don't know what your ultimate objective is, so I don't know if that's good enough.

Comment: Based on comment by @lericr ; I am on Win7-x64, v12.2.0, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8wi.png)

Comment: @lecrir Thank you, the workaround works perfectly for my use case. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit in case someone has a more general answer or explanation.